# Writing to stream with simultaneous sending to HTTP controller in .NET

Tags: c#, .net, stream

We have a Server API endpoint that can read HTTP Body as a `Stream` and parse it to very large collection of our entities. We implemented parsing of stream using [JsonTextReader](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/readjsonwithjsontextreader.htm) (`Newtonsoft.Json` package). And this process works fine, we are able to read stream partially and add items to collection while stream data is loading.

Our Client App prepares `StreamContent` and makes an HTTP request to Server API. Right now we use standard [HttpClient](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient?view=net-7.0) class for sending data. We have implemented request as described here:

```
public async Task<OutputModel> SendStreamAsync(Stream stream, CancellationToken cancellation)
{
    if (stream.CanSeek)
    {
        stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
    }

    var body = new StreamContent(stream);

    var response = await _httpClient.PostAsync(url, body, cancellation);

    var content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync(cancellation);

    ...

    return result;
}
```

But we prepared a **FULL** stream in memory and only after it we send `StreamContent` to HTTP endpoint in current realization. Of course the stream can be large, and we use `JsonWriter` to write data to stream partially.

**Our goal**:

1. Start sending `StreamContent` request to HTTP Endpoint while we still writing new data to existing `Stream`.
2. When Server API receives first portion of data, we want to start reading and parsing of uploaded data (without waiting full data uploading).

Is it possible to implement in .NET?
I believe we need to use something else than standard HttpClient implementation.

Any help will be highly appreciated.

---

*UPDATE 1*

Our Server API method is here:

```
[ApiController]
[Route("api/master")]
public class MasterController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpPost("event")]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Load()
    {
        // Parse JSON from Request Body
        var events = ParseStreamAsync(HttpContext.Request.Body, HttpContext.RequestAborted);

        // Run external library with our events data
        await _eventLoaderService.AppendEventsAsync(events, HttpContext.RequestAborted);

        return NoContent();
    }
    
    private async IAsyncEnumerable<EventData> ParseStreamAsync(Stream stream, [EnumeratorCancellation] CancellationToken cancellation)
    {
        var serializer = new JsonSerializer
        {
            MissingMemberHandling = MissingMemberHandling.Error
        };

        using var sr = new StreamReader(stream);
        await using var reader = new JsonTextReader(sr);
        while (await ReadAsync(reader, cancellation))
        {
            if (reader.TokenType == JsonToken.PropertyName && reader.Path.Equals("Events", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
            {
                await ReadAsync(reader, cancellation);

                while (await ReadAsync(reader, cancellation))
                {
                    var @event = new Event();
                
                    ...
                    
                    yield return @event;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why not let your parent web-server handle this (i.e. a reverse-proxy), such as `nginx` or IIS' ARR? Seems inefficient to pipe it into ASP.NET Core if it's only coming out again...

Comment: When you say "the stream can be quite large" - can you give us a general idea? Kilobytes? Megabytes? Gigabytes? If you're exchanging multi-megabyte-sized JSON documents around I'd say you have a major architectural design flaw going on... JSON isn't meant for moving data around like that...

Comment: I think is not HttpClient stuff, it's your server that loads data in memory. are you using asp.net core in your server?

Comment: @AliYousefi yes, we use ASP.NET Core Server.

Comment: @Dai it can be 1 - 2 Gigabytes.

Comment: @AlexanderI. ...you don't see a problem there?

Comment: @AlexanderI. Could we have your server method?

Comment: @AliYousefi Thanks for your attention. I have provided code snippet of Server API controller.

Comment: Ok, @AlexanderI. Let's use PushStreamContent instead of StreamContent, and tell me did I fix your problem?

Comment: @AliYousefi thanks for your comment. PushStreamContent looks very interesting. But I need a time to implement and test it. In any case please add this solution as an answer and I will upvote your answer. I will inform you when I will test this. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it's possible to achieve streaming data to your API endpoint without waiting for the entire stream to be prepared in memory. .NET provides ways to stream data asynchronously, and you can modify your client implementation to achieve this.

To achieve streaming data to the API while continuously writing new data to the existing stream, you can use `HttpClient` with `HttpContent` derived types, like `PushStreamContent`. This class allow streaming content as it's being written.

Class `PushStreamContent` available in separate [Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client/) nuget package.

Here's an example of how you can modify your code to achieve this:

```
public async Task<OutputModel> SendStreamAsync(Stream stream, CancellationToken cancellation)
{
    // Seek if possible
    if (stream.CanSeek)
    {
        stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
    }

    // Create a PushStreamContent to allow streaming
    var pushStreamContent = new PushStreamContent(async (outputStream, httpContent, transportContext) =>
    {
        // Use a buffer or other mechanism to write data to the outputStream as it becomes available
        // Example: Write chunks of data to the outputStream using JsonWriter
        // Ensure cancellation is respected for async operations within this block
        // Example:
        using (var jsonWriter = new JsonTextWriter(new StreamWriter(outputStream)))
        {
            // Your logic here to write JSON data chunks to the outputStream
            // You can continuously write data to outputStream as it becomes available
            // For demo purposes, let's assume you're writing a JSON array
            await jsonWriter.WriteStartArrayAsync();

            // Simulate writing data in chunks (replace this with your actual logic)
            for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                var jsonString = $"{{ \"item\": {i} }}";
                await jsonWriter.WriteRawValueAsync(jsonString);
                await Task.Delay(100); // Simulate writing delay
            }

            await jsonWriter.WriteEndArrayAsync();
        }
    });

    // Make the POST request with the PushStreamContent
    var response = await _httpClient.PostAsync(url, pushStreamContent, cancellation);

    var content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync(cancellation);

    // Process response...

    return result;
}
```

Also more details can be found on Stephen Cleary [article](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2016/10/async-pushstreamcontent.html).

Answer (score 2):

Use `PushStreamContent` instead of `StreamContent`.

Here is an example of how you could set up your client to send a stream asynchronously as it's being written:

```cs
public async Task<OutputModel> SendStreamAsync(Stream stream, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    var requestMessage = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, url);
    requestMessage.Content = new PushStreamContent(async (requestStream, httpContent, transportContext) =>
    {
        using (yourstream)
        {
            await stream.CopyToAsync(requestStream);
        }
    });

    using var response = await _httpClient.SendAsync(requestMessage, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead, cancellationToken);
  
    if (!response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
        // Handle error response
    }

    var content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync(cancellationToken);
  
    var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<OutputModel>(content);

    return result;
}
```